# Efficient way to find all subsets of Σ that generate S7

Tags: group-theory

I am currently practising for my upcomming Algebra exam and came upon this problem.

> We define Σ to be the following set of elements of the symmetric group
> S7:
>
> Σ := {(1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)}. Determine all of the
> subsets of Σ, that generate S7.

I am confident that I could list all the subsets manually, but I also think that this would take quite some time to finish. Given that this problem is from an old exam I can hardly imagine that this is the best way to approach this problem.

Does somebody have an idea how I could approach this in a better way?

Comment: There are only eight subsets, and it should be clear that subsets of size $0$ and $1$ cannot generate $S_7$. That leaves $4$ subsets. Is that really too many to do individually? In  fact there is one subset of size $2$ that obviously does not generate $S_7$, so that leaves just $3$ that might need a bit of work. Just go ahead and do it!

Comment: For the remaining subsets needing to be checked, recall what you know about even vs odd permutations to immediately eliminate another possibility.  That leaves only two options left... only one of which still needs effort to be checked since the other is a superset of this.  It should be a well known example that was proven in class or homework that it does generate S7.

Comment: Thank you two for your answers. It seems that I was left in the wrong belive that I had to do again subsets of the sets given like {1} or {1,3}. So if this is not the case the you two are right, there are not many left. But now I am a little confused about what you said. So you say that {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} does not generate S7? How come? Or did I again misunderstand?

Comment: To be clear, it is $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$, not $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.  It is the 7-cycle who when applied one time moves $1$ to $2$, who moves $2$ to $3$, and so on.  If you imagine a regular 7-gon with points labeled $1,2,3,\dots,7$ in clockwise order with 1 at the top... the only other labelings you can achieve by repeated application of the 7-cycle $(1,2,\dots,7)$ would be those made by rotating the entire image.  You will not ever have a way to reorder the labelings to have 2,1,3,4,5,6,7 in that order for instance.

Comment: The title asks a very different question from what the post asks.

Comment: 40 minutes ago I belived, that that was the same question. I possess now more knowledge and will try to find a short title that descirbes the problem.

Comment: I gave this question some more thought and came to the conclusion that the only subset that generates S7 would be (1,2,3,4,5,6,7). Since (1,2)(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)=(3,1,4,5,6,7,2) and (1,2,3)(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)=(2,3,4,5,6,7,2) are no permutations of S7. Does that make sense?

Comment: Title still asks a different question than the post, and it asks a trivial question: a **subgroup** generates $S_7$ if and only if it is all of $S_7$, and $\Sigma$ is not a group, so it does not have subgroups.

Comment: So since you only criticise the title, I take it that my attempt to a solution is not all that wrong?

Comment: I am afraid that your attempt is completely wrong, and no it doesn't make sense. As I said in my first comment, a subset of size $1$ cannot generate $S_7$, because $S_7$ is not a cyclic group. In particular $\{(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)\}$ generates a subgroup of order $7$, which is clearly not the whole of $S_7$. You ought to know already that the subset $\{(1,2),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)\}$ generates $S_7$.

Comment: @Irina No, you should assume that if you can't be bothered to write a title accurately, then I won't bothered trying to read your math. If you fail the threshold issue of accurately stating the question, **twice**, I see no reason to waste time with anything else.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with some basic facts about cycles and generating sets for $S_n$ you can save yourself some work. An excellent discussion is in [this expository note](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf) by Keith Conrad.

A standard fact about cycles is that $(1, \dots, n) = (1,2)(2,3)\dots(n-1,n)$, so that when $n$ is odd, $(1, \dots, n)$ is a product of an even number of transpositions. That should enable you to assess whether $\{(1,2,3),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)\}$ is generating, bearing in mind JMoravitz's comment.

A standard generating set for $S_n$ is $\{(1,2), (1,2,\dots,n)\}$, and from there the answer to the question is straightforward.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was very helpful.

Comment: @Irina Welcome to MSE! Glad you found it helpful. The etiquette on this site is to upvote or accept answers, not thank people in comments. It helps users see which questions have been answered, and what the best answers are. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10637/how-to-quote-and-link-in-a-comment) for more information.